# 403 (Forbidden) jquery permissions in cakephp

Tags: php, linux, apache, bash, debian

hi well I have  a problem in my localhost because there is a problem when the apache want have access to `/cake/soyaproductorcompras/validate_form` I give all permissions to mi files I dont know what is the problem.the code is fine I did a test in the cloud.
now I am using debian wheezy, cakephp, apache.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/cake/soyaproductorcompras/validate_form 403 (Forbidden)
```

And in my file of webroot/js This folder also has permissions.
[image: permissions of mi folders]

this only happens when I use this script.

Comment: Is something using port 8080 already, like Skype?

Comment: yes I am using port 8080.

Comment: I don't have installed skype.

Comment: I think this is more Linux related than anything. You probably have your permissions set up and will need to chmod them or something like that.

Comment: yeah well he tried giving chmod permissions do not work for me either. something weird happened, works a moment and then returned the same error.